Docker container don't connect to Postgres Pg Admin
I am running this code at WSL
docker run -d --name postgres-container \
\-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
\-e POSTGRES_USER=root \
\-e POSTGRES_DB=financeapp \
\-v \~/postgres/finance-app:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
\-p 5432:5432 \
postgres

And when i try to connect Postgres Pg Admin with the docker container it happens:
I tried to connect to docker container

what's happens??? Anyway, try get ip of container (postgres) and conect on ip:port

How are you trying to connect?
Best way to connect it by using 0.0.0.0 IP
if you have errors check with the following command
Is the port is Listening
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep 5432

connect via
psql -h 0.0.0.0 -U root -d financeapp

Look for errors with
docker logs postgres-container


0.0.0.0 is a special address that means "all interfaces".  In a Docker context it's important that a process listen on "all interfaces", but it doesn't make sense to connect to it, for example as the psql -h option.
